# Javascript, need to change background image based on switch/variable

Tags: javascript, css, background

I am making a computer game on Twine, which accepts html, javascript, css.

I am trying to display images based on the state of the game.

This code below, works correctly i shows all 3 images overlapping correctly.

However, i want to display other images based on game state. For example if the player is at 20% health, it should display 2a.pgn instead of 2.pgn
or if it is poisoned, it should show 3a.pgn instead of 3.

And so on and so on, it does not make sense having to specify all possible combinations. Instead i just want to change a single layer at a time based on a variable/switch.

```
<html>
<div class="a1"></div>
<style>
.a1 {
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
background-image: url(3.png),url(2.png),url(1.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
</style>
</html>
```

Could you please help?

Thank you very much.

Cheers,

Comment: i think you mean .png not .pgn? Always a good start to get the image extension right!

Comment: post your javascript and a description of how the game works would also be helpful; we're not mindreaders - what does the health depend on?? A switch statement is fairly easy. Try google

Comment: Hey, Magma! I would love to help you, but I'll need your JS to help. I think that you should also consider the possibility of programming your image using code instead of images, as they are easier to manipulate.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies so far. My coding is fairly limited，and one of the reasons i am using twine as the fame engine. I will try to see if i get any improvements and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways - setting url() (and preloading everything on load), changing visibility, opacity or z-index, but if you want to stick with multiple backgrounds:

```
//imageIndex - your image for given HP
//imagesLen - images count
var HPimgArr = Array(imagesLen).fill('-9999px 0');
HPimgArr[imageIndex] = '0 0';
document.querySelector('.a1').style.backgroundPosition = HPimgArr.join(', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to Javascript try this (you need jQuery for this):

```
var maxHealth = 10;
var health = 10; //He is apparently at full health

function updateHealth(newHealth){
    health = newHealth;
    if(health < maxHealth / 5) {
        var stats = $('.a1').css('background-image').split(','); //Put every different stat in array
        stats[1] = 'url(2a.png)';
        $('.a1').css('background-image', stats.toString());
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to change his health call `updateHealth(...)`.
I haven't tested this but something along these lines should work.